# How to Sum data by every month in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I can select the sum by year, which is easy.

Just like this.

```
var query = from t in ctx.SomeDataEntity
                            group t by t.DateAdded.Year into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Year = g.Year,
                                Total = g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn1) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn2) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn3) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn4)
                            };
```

But, how to filter the data by every month?
It is not easy as simply replacing t.DateAdded.Year to t.DateAdded.Month, cause t.DateAdded.Month is 1,2,3,...,12.
I need the one is in format of 2014-01,2014-02,...,2014-12.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703593/writing-group-by-on-anonymous-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by both Year and Month like this:

```
var query = from t in ctx.SomeDataEntity
                    group t by new 
                    { 
                        Year = t.DateAdded.Year, 
                        Month = t.DateAdded.Month 
                    } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        MonthAndYear = g.Key.Year + "-" + g.Key.Month,
                        Total = g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn1) +
                        g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn2) +
                        g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn3) +
                        g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn4)
                    };
```

Comment: 1. Can you refer g.Year without Key? 2. What type is g.Year?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri 1) good catch, you need the .Key property, 2) its just an int.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by both the month and year:

```
var query = from t in ctx.SomeDataEntity
                        group t by new { Month = t.DateAdded.Month, Year = t.DateAdded.Year } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Year = g.Key.Year,
                            Month = g.Key.Month,
                            Total = g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn1) +
                            g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn2) +
                            g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn3) +
                            g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn4)
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = from t in ctx.SomeDataEntity
                            group t by new { t.DateAdded.Year, t.DateAdded.Month} into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Year = g.Key.Year,
                                Month = g.Key.Month,
                                Total = g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn1) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn2) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn3) +
                                g.Sum(t => t.SomeColumn4)
                            };
```